# "Dependency 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2:2.3.5.RELEASE' not found "

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

I'm new to Maven and I'm adding some dependencies to my `pom.xml` file, but a couple of the dependencies I added keep saying something along the lines of:

> Dependency
> 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2:2.3.5.RELEASE'
> not found

Does this mean that this package no longer exists? Or, it's not found within my project? Do I need to add some jar file to my source path? Any help/comment is appreciated.

Comment: That's certainly a valid dependency, and Maven *should* be able to find it (and download it):  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-log4j2/2.3.5.RELEASE.  Q: Does Maven find *any* of your dependencies? One place to look is `.m2\repository` (hidden) under your %USERPROFILE% (Windows) or $HOME (Linux) directory.  Q: Does `mvn clean install -U` help?

Comment: IntelliJ later offered an option to refresh my maven dependencies? and I reloaded, which then seemed to have installed them because I do see them in the .m2 folder. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Seeing your POM might help diagnose the issue.

Comment: SUGGESTION: Please post the problem (Spring Boot project in IntelliJ IDE, copy/paste error message) and the solution (IntelliJ > Refresh Maven).  You can then "accept" your solution.  This will help others if they encounter a similar problem.

Comment: Let's post all of your `pom.xml` file(s)!

Answer (score 1):

The error seemed to have been resolved by simply refreshing Maven Changes. Once you're done editing your dependencies, this icon will appear to 'Load Maven Changes' which will install your packages.

[image]

Here is my pom file below for reference:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.daisymdev</groupId>
<artifactId>socialmediaapi</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<parent>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <version>2.3.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-log4j2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.13</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jayway.jsonpath/json-path -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: In IDEA Intellij there you can toggle that behaviour via going to Actions and `Toggle Auto-Reload-Mode` than you don't need to click every time on that icon when you change something in your pom file..

Comment: If you are using the spring-boot parent you should never mention a version of a dependency like spring-boot-starter-log4j2, sprint-boot-start-data-jpa, spring-security-crypto etc. manually...they are all controlled by the parent. So remove the versions defined also strongly recommend not to use Junit 3/4 anymore start using JUnit Jupiter instead...

Comment: Thank you! these comments really help